# Liferay 7 docbar custom notification

Tags: liferay

In Liferay 6.2 we used to configure Custom User Notification Hander class and User Notification XML file in the custom portlet as in “**liferay-portlet.xml**” file. To achieve the same in Liferay 7 OSGI module portlet, can anyone guide me where I find it?

Comment: What's the configuration you're doing? "the same" is not quite descriptive

Comment: i have not configured anything yet. In Liferay 7 default xml files are not available so im confused where i can configure those files